# JSOM save indicator/semaphore (locked ListItem)

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I am using standard JSOM code to update one ListItem **on every keyup event**

Typing (too) fast causes a JSOM error
(because the back-end has not yet finished saving the list-item, so it is locked *I presume*)

Does JSOM have a semaphore indicating it is currently busy saving an item, i can use?

Comment: No I don't think so. JS being single threaded. If you are making an asynchronous ajax call to make your update, a solution might be using call back function to process the next character.